# Loading relational data in GraphQL & MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, graphql

This is my schema:

```
type User {
    _id: ID!
    username: String
    email: String!
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    avatar: String
    createdAt: Date!
    updatedAt: Date!
}

type Tweet {
    _id: ID!
    text: String!
    user: User!
    favoriteCount: Int!
    createdAt: Date!
    updatedAt: Date!
}
```

and here's my `Tweet` model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const TweetSchema = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,
        minLength: [5, 'Your tweet is too short.'],
        maxLength: [144, 'Your tweet is too long.']
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    favoriteCount: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }
}, { timestamps: true });

export default mongoose.model('Tweet', TweetSchema);
```

the above GraphQL schema is served by express like this:

```
import { graphqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

import typeDefs from '../graphql/schema';
import resolvers from '../graphql/resolvers';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers
});

const app = express();
app.use(
    '/graphql', 
    graphqlExpress(req => ({ 
        schema
    }))
);
```

I use the following code to mock up some users and tweet using faker like this:

https://pastebin.com/raw/kJ9m8KjR

When the whole thing runs, I can see the mongodb is populated with dummy tweets linked to a user like this:

[image]

but when I query this via GraphiQL, the user info is not coming through:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share your resolvers code ?

Comment: hi. here it is the tweet resolvers: https://pastebin.com/raw/tGSixdMe

Comment: and its used like this https://pastebin.com/raw/5jJ1jZDn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your resolver gets the Tweets like this:

```
Tweet.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```

If you check out the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), you'll notice you need to tell mongoose to replace the id reference with an actual document by using populate:

```
Tweet.find({}).populate('user').sort({ createdAt: -1 });
```